# How to Write Simple Hibernate Criteria Subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

How can I write this SQL query as a Hibernate JPA Criteria (with Restrictions, etc) in Java ?

`SELECT q.*
    FROM queue AS q
    WHERE q.executed = false AND
        q.queued_on = (SELECT min(queued_on) FROM queue WHERE item_id = q.item_id);`

I only managed to write the first part like this:

```
getBaseCriteria()
    .add(Restrictions.eq("executed", false))
    // Missing Second Where Filter Here
    .addOrder(Order.asc("queuedOn"))
    .list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a separate criteria instance for the subquery and simply add as another restriction as follows:

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Queue.class, "sub")
    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("sub.itemId","main.itemId"))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.min("sub.queuedOn")));

session.createCriteria(Queue.class, "main")
   .add(Subqueries.propertyEq("main.queuedOn", subCriteria ));
   .add(Restrictions.eq("main.executed", false));
   .addOrder(Order.asc("main.queuedOn"))
   .list();
```

Comment: `session.createCriteria` is deprecated in 5.2